# What is kernel $\phi:G\rightarrow \pi_1(X/G,p(x_0))$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-group

Let $G$ be a discontinuous group (this means that it acts discontinuously with finite stabilizers) of homeomorphisms of a simply connected, locally compact metric space $X$. Let $p:X\rightarrow X/G$ be the orbit map. Choose a base point $x_0\in X$ and let $\pi_1(X/G,p(x_0))$ be the fundamental group of $X/G$.

Define $\phi:G\rightarrow \pi_1(X/G,p(x_0))$ as follows - for any $g\in G$ let $\alpha$ be a path from $x_0$ to $g(x_0)$. Send $g$ to the homotopy class of loops $p\circ\alpha$. This map is independent of the choice of path as $X$ is simply connected. It is also easy to check that it is a group homomorphism.

We can show that for a discontinuous group of homeomorphisms of a locally compact metric space, $p:X\rightarrow X/G$ has the path lifting property. This helps show that $\phi$ is surjective.

> What I want to know is **what is the kernel of $\phi$?**

I know that $\pi_1(X/G,p(x_0)) \cong G/N$ where $N$ is the normal subroup generated by all those elements of $G$ that have fixed points. So my guess is that $\ker\phi\cong N$ but I am not sure how to show this. If $g\in G$ has a fixed point say $g(x)=x$ then we can join $x_0$ to $x$ by a path $\gamma$ and use $\gamma*(g\circ\gamma)^{-1}$ to join $x_0$ to $g(x_0)$. Then I have to show $p\circ(\gamma*(g\circ\gamma)^{-1})$ is null homotopic in $X/G$. But what about the other way that is given a null homotopic loop in $X/G$ why should it come from a $g$ with has a fixed point?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems that any proof showing that $\pi_1(X/G,p(x_0))\cong G/N$ would also prove that $\ker\phi\cong N$. Then as you said, $N$ is generated as a normal subgroup by elements with fixed points. This does not imply that any element in $N$ has a fixed point itself. For example, let $X=\mathbb R$ and let $G$ be generated by the reflections at $0$ and $1$. Then $X/G\cong[0,1]$ and $G=N$, but $G$ contains translations by even integers that have no fixed points.

Comment: @SebastianGoette The proof that $\pi_1(X/G,p(x_0))\cong G/N$ is from a paper by M A Armstrong. He first proves that if $G$ is discontinuous and generated by its elements having fixed points and $X$ is simply connected, locally compact then $X/G$ is simply connected. Then he proves that if $G$ is discontinuous and acts freely then $\pi_1(X/G)\cong G$. And finally factors the action of $G$ into a discontinuous action of $N$ on $X$ followed by a free discontinuous action of $G/N$ on $X/N$. He doesn't directly prove $\ker\phi\cong N$

Comment: Do you want G to act by homeomorphisms on X or by isometries?

Comment: Also if X is a CW complex and G acts combinatorially (maps cells to cells) there is a nice answer to your question.

Comment: @NWMT, by homeomorphisms. Not isometries

Answer (score 3):

Note that if a group $G$ acts on a space $X$ then $G$ also acts on the fundamental groupoid $\pi_1(X)$.

The study of the **fundamental groupoid** of an orbit space is developed in Chapter 11 of [Topology and Groupoids](http://grouopids.org.uk/topgpds.html), (T&G). An older version of this Chapter is available at [arXiv:math/0212271](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0212271).

The main result is to link the fundamental groupoid of an orbit space to the notion of **orbit groupoid**. The analysis of orbit groupoids uses  **fibrations of groupoids**, which are also applied in Chapter 7 of T&G to yield operations of fundamental groupoids and exact sequences.

Here is a main result on the orbit groupoid $\Gamma //G$ of an action of a group $G$ on a groupoid $\Gamma$. (It comes from J. Taylor, "Quotients of a groupoid by the action of a group", Math. Proc. Camb. Phil. Soc 103 (1988) 239-249.)

**11.5.2** The orbit morphism $p : \Gamma \to \Gamma // G$ is a
fibration whose kernel is generated as a subgroupoid of $\Gamma$
by all elements of the form $\gamma - g\cdot \gamma$ where $g$
stabilises the initial point of $\gamma$. Furthermore,

(a) 
if $G$ acts freely
on $\Gamma$, by which we mean no non-identity element of $G$ fixes
an object of $\Gamma$, then $p$ is a covering morphism;

(b)
if $\Gamma$  is connected and $G$  is
generated by those of its elements which fix some object of
$\Gamma$, then $p$ is a quotient morphism; in particular, $p$ is a
quotient morphism if the action of $G$ on $Ob(\Gamma)$ has a
fixed point;

(c)
if $\Gamma$  is a tree groupoid, then
each object group of $\Gamma // G$ is isomorphic to the
factor group of $G$ by the (normal) subgroup of $G$ generated by
elements which have fixed points.

You can also find out more on applications of fibrations of groupoids from [arxiv:1207.6404](http://arxiv.org/abs/1207.6404).